# Add SqsEventSource to Lambda (Amplify CLI)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-cdk, aws-amplify-cli

recently i was trying to do this tutorial: https://awstip.com/implementing-sqs-queue-with-lambda-in-aws-amplify-using-cloudformation-d7bd8a0ae3d4

I successfully added LambdaFunctionSQSMapping manually following it, and it works.

But I'm trying to do this with `amplify add custom` using cdk.

I can't do the same as tutorial with cdk programatically.

Could anybody help me please?

cdk-stack.ts:

```js
import * as AmplifyHelpers from '@aws-amplify/cli-extensibility-helper';
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { SqsEventSource } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-event-sources';
import * as sqs from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-sqs';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { AmplifyDependentResourcesAttributes } from '../../types/amplify-dependent-resources-ref';

export class cdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(
        scope: Construct,
        id: string,
        props?: cdk.StackProps,
        amplifyResourceProps?: AmplifyHelpers.AmplifyResourceProps
    ) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        /* Do not remove - Amplify CLI automatically injects the current deployment environment in this input parameter */
        new cdk.CfnParameter(this, 'env', {
            type: 'String',
            description: 'Current Amplify CLI env name'
        });
        /* AWS CDK code goes here - learn more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html */

        const amplifyProjectInfo = AmplifyHelpers.getProjectInfo();
        const sqsQueueResourceNamePrefix = `sqs-correos-${amplifyProjectInfo.projectName}`;
        const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'sqs-queue', {
            queueName: `${sqsQueueResourceNamePrefix}-${cdk.Fn.ref('env')}.fifo`,
            fifo: true,
            contentBasedDeduplication: true
        });

        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'QueueUrl', {
            value: queue.queueUrl,
            description: 'SQS Queue URL'
        });

        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'QueueArn', {
            value: queue.queueArn,
            description: 'SQS Queue ARN'
        });

        new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'QueueName', {
            value: queue.queueName,
            description: 'SQS Queue Name'
        });

        const roleResourceNamePrefix = `CustomRole-${amplifyProjectInfo.projectName}`;

        const role = new iam.Role(this, 'CustomRole', {
            assumedBy: new iam.AccountRootPrincipal(),
            roleName: `${roleResourceNamePrefix}-${cdk.Fn.ref('env')}`
        });

        role.addToPolicy(
            new iam.PolicyStatement({
                actions: ['sqs:SendMessage', 'sqs:ReceiveMessage', 'sqs:DeleteMessage', 'sqs:GetQueueUrl'],
                resources: [queue.queueArn]
            })
        );

        // Access other Amplify Resources
        const dependencies: AmplifyDependentResourcesAttributes = AmplifyHelpers.addResourceDependency(
            this,
            amplifyResourceProps.category,
            amplifyResourceProps.resourceName,
            [{ category: 'function', resourceName: 'procesarCorreo' }]
        );

        // load lambda Role to attach policy
        const lambdaRole = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(
            this,
            cdk.Fn.importValue(dependencies.function.procesarCorreo.LambdaExecutionRole),
            cdk.Fn.importValue(dependencies.function.procesarCorreo.LambdaExecutionRoleArn)
        );

        const policy1 = new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: [
                'sqs:ReceiveMessage',
                'sqs:DeleteMessage',
                'sqs:GetQueueAttributes',
                'sqs:GetQueueUrl',
                'sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility'
            ],
            resources: [queue.queueArn],
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW
        });

        lambdaRole.attachInlinePolicy(
            new iam.Policy(this, 'receive-events', {
                statements: [policy1]
            })
        );

        // Attach EventSource
        const sqseve = new SqsEventSource(queue);

        const lambdaProcesarCorreo = lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(
            this,
            cdk.Fn.importValue(dependencies.function.procesarCorreo.Name),
            {
                functionArn: cdk.Fn.importValue(dependencies.function.procesarCorreo.Arn),
                role: lambdaRole
            }
        );

        lambdaProcesarCorreo.addEventSource(sqseve);
    }
}
```

Error when i do ``àmplify push --debug -y```

```
 There was an error building the custom resources
Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: ID components may not include unresolved tokens: ${Token[TOKEN.1200]}.
Object creation stack:
  at Execute again with CDK_DEBUG=true to capture stack traces.
Object creation stack:
  at Execute again with CDK_DEBUG=true to capture stack traces..
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `lambdaProcesarCorreo` construct's ID is causing the error.  Construct IDs must be available at synth-time, but `cdk.Fn.importValue` will only resolve [later](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html), at deploy-time.

Either hard-code the ID or use a variable that's defined in your CDK code.

```js
const lambdaProcesarCorreo = lambda.Function.fromFunctionAttributes(
      this,
      "FunctionReference", //  Construct ID - remove the intrinsic function
      {
          functionArn: cdk.Fn.importValue(dependencies.function.procesarCorreo.Arn),
          role: lambdaRole
      }
  );
```

Comment: same error :( 
```
 There was an error building the custom resources
Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: Resolution error: ID components may not include unresolved tokens: ${Token[TOKEN.1204]}.
Object creation stack:
  at Execute again with CDK_DEBUG=true to capture stack traces.
Object creation stack:
  at Execute again with CDK_DEBUG=true to capture stack traces..

```